# OutOfMemoryError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

When I work in Eclipse for a while, I always get this Exception and I have to restart the server. Why does this happen? Is something going very wrong?

> SEVERE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`
>   `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException`: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [`/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml`]; nested exception is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: PermGen space

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info than that. What server are you talking about and how relevant is it to the problem you're having? What are the specs (both hardware and relevant software like OS)? What do you have in your `eclipse.ini` for the values of `-Xmx` and `-Xms`?

Comment: Not sure if this is an exact duplicate, but you should look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing your PermGen space is fairly easy.  You can increase it for all of you projects in Eclipse by going to the eclipse.ini file and changing the parameter `-XX:MaxPermSize` to whatever size fits your needs.  You will see what the current size of it is and figure out from there what you want to change it to.  If you want to increase the PermGen size for just that single project, click on the dropdown next to the run button and click on `Run Configurations`.  Click on the arguments tab and add the same argument with the new size into the args text area.  For example: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`