# How to increase java memory space

Tags: java, memory, permgen

I encounter `java out of memory: perm gen exception`. I tried to resolve it by expanding the java heap size, but unable to solve it. How can I increase the memory?

Comment: is it for standalone java app or a webapp in a web container?

Comment: Have you tried search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

Comment: web container, IDE: eclipse, server: apache tomcat.

Comment: This article is very well explained [Tomcat Memory Inside Eclipse](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_increase_tomcat_memory_inside_eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a directive like this when starting Java: `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

PermGen is where class definitions and such are stored. It's not part of the same body of memory that is referenced by things like `Xmx` and `Xms`.

Comment: where should I add it?