# how to prevent PemGen space error in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

After 2 to 3 deployments, I'm continuously  getting PemSpace Error in windows8. I have been trying with different approaches like setting pemgen variables as java start parameter in Apache  but no idea worked .could anyone help me in resolving this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error?rq=1

Comment: Go to java 8 as there is no more such an error...

Comment: @StathisAndronikos that is not always possible =\ ...

Comment: You mean that you changed the server configuration variable `XX:MaxPermSize` and nothing happened?

Comment: What is the size of your `.war` file?

Comment: Where did you set the permgen variable? Are you launching tomcat from eclipse?

Comment: War file size is 31MB and I tried setting it in control panel ->administrative tools -->services -->apache tomcat console -->start parameters

Comment: Thanks stathis for saying this

Answer (score 1):

Hot deployments tend to cause perm-gen bloat. There's not much you can do about it other than restarting Tomcat after each deployment.

Use `jstat` or add `-verbose:gc` to the command line to monitor the Perm Space.