# Bytecode generated access objects vs GeneratedMethodAccessor

Tags: java, performance, bytecode

I have bean util library and we cache `Method`/`Fields` of properties, of course. Reading and writing goes via reflection.

There is an idea to skip reflection and for each method/field to bytecode-generate a simple object that directly calls the target. For example, if we have `setFoo(String s)` method, we would call a `set(String s)` method of this generated class that internally calls `setFoo()`. Again, we are replacing the reflection call with the runtime generated direct call.

I know Java does similar thing with `GeneratedMethodAccessor`. But it's cache may be limited by JVM argument.

Does anyone know if it make sense to roll-on my implementation, considering the performance? On one hand, it sounds fine, but on other, there are many new classes that will be created - and fill perm gen space.

Any experience on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to re-invent cglib's [FastMethod](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/reflect/FastMethod.html)
In fact, Reflection is not slower at all. See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580143/3448419

Reflection can do more than 50,000,000 invocations per second. It is unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for the link. My tests were with similar results - no statistically significant difference. Thank you!