# deployment and "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen exception"

Tags: java, jboss

I have a number of WAR files that I manage for QA , I tend to use the JBoss command line utility to manage to deploy these applications on JBoss 7

After I undeploy a war file, and try to deploy it again, I often get permgen exception, which sometimes get resolved by waiting few minutes and attempt to deploy the application again.

the other option is to restart the server and deploy the applications.

My question would be is there is a way to clear unused memory in jboss 7, so I can avoid restarting the application server?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PermGen as the name suggest is Permanent Memory, which cannot be utilized (until Java8 which use Metaspace). Most common behavior is restarting application server (Jboss), or use 3rd party software to manage deployment e.g. JRebel.

#### References

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace