# Tomcat run time war deployment error

Tags: java, tomcat

tomcat supports war deployment @ run time ???

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

when deploying multiple war files run time tomcat permGen out-of memory error occurring ,stop tomcat and deploy and restart that time error not coming.what is actual cause for this error. is there any tomcat configuration problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following arguments in the JVM command line when Tomcat is started:

> -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled

To do so, shut down the tomcat service, then go to the Tomcat/bin directory and run tomcat6w.exe. Under the "Java" tab, add the arguments to the "Java Options" box. Click "OK" and then restart the service.

If you get an error the specified service does not exist as an installed service you should run:

tomcat6w //ES//servicename
where servicename is the name of the server as viewed in services.msc