# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in Jetty Linux

Tags: java, jetty

I am using jetty and running in linux(opensuse).
I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error again and again.
Below is the error trace. Please help me to resolve issue

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
      at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
      at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
      at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error with Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989092/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error-with-jetty)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error?rq=1 exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Permgen is the memory space for the bytecode, not the data. Increase the permgen size (I assume you are using Java 7 or older...)