# Netlogo Headless error

Tags: netlogo

I get this error while running NetLogo, headless on HPC. I job seems to keep running but doesn't write anything.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
            at org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:27)
            at org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadBytecodeClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:32)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.finish(Generator.scala:241)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generate(Generator.scala:93)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator.org$nlogo$generator$Generator$$recurse(Generator.scala:28)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator$$anonfun$generate$1.apply(Generator.scala:24)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator$$anonfun$generate$1.apply(Generator.scala:24)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.map(ArrayOps.scala:38)
            at org.nlogo.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.scala:24)
            at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$3.apply(CompilerMain.scala:59)
            at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$3.apply(CompilerMain.scala:50)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
            at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:50)
            at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:28)
            at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromMap(HeadlessModelOpener.scala:53)
            at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openString(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:525)
            at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:507)
            at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.newWorkspace$1(Main.scala:19)
            at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
            at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
            at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$1.apply(Lab.scala:33)
            at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$1.apply(Lab.scala:33)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
```

Comment: It seems like some kind of stack overflow. You might want to post the code that makes this error pop.

Comment: @DavidMerinos Are you asking for the netlogo code or the job script?

Comment: @DavidMerinos I think it is because too great the number of threads specified leading to more simulation threads per processor. Does that make sense? Reducing threads solved it.

Comment: Yes it could be, you can read a _.OutOfMemoryError:_ in the log.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the memory size setting in netlogo batch file may solve this issue. as the default low of maximum memory is low, this issue usually happens when you hae a simulation with large quantity of agents.

change it to 1024M is what i did before. try to make your own script and submit it with local modified netlogo batch instead using the standard version provided by hpc.