# Java web service Tomcat overload

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have a problem from my web hosting provider with errors, does anyone know what the problem could be?

In app I have implemented ORM *hibernate* to connect the database and tables.

How can I optimize the app?

```
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Deploying web application archive /home/joco/webapps/service.war
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/service] - Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@1a28adb, hello.Application@4a5ac2]
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/service] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Deploying web application archive /home/joco/webapps/ROOT.war
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/] - No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/] - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Deploying web application archive /home/joco/webapps/report.war
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/report] - Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [hello.Application@5be2b]
INFO jo.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jo.com].[/report] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
ERROR Catalina-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:766)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1402)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Comment: How much memory do you have, and how much did you give Tomcat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Comment: Could you post tomcat parameters? JAVA_OPTS? CATALINA_OPTS? etc.

Comment: It is shared hosting, tomcat is not in mine hands unfortunately.