# Build Best Practices to avoid Classloader leaks - OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, classloader, wildfly, maven-bom

I was reading some post around here about OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space.  This one here took a special attention. [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Also, this same post mentions other web references

- http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html
  http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html

As far as I understood the ClassLoader leak is, in some cases, associated with a deployment that have classes present inside the App ClassLoader which are beeing referenced from outside the App ClassLoader.  The links in this posts illustrates an example, a Custom log Level.

Said that, my doubt is about Best Practice for Builds and Dependency Management.  I use Maven and Bill of Materials with dependency analysis to check if I am not generate a package with more than I need.  So far, so good.  But I know that there is a precedence of Class Loader.  In my case I use JBoss AS / WildFly that uses the UnifiedClassLoader.

In that case should I take in consideration that a WAR file built with Maven and BOM may have the same behavior as the example of the Logger?  Is it still recommended to use BOM?

Comment: There is no relationship with Maven itself or using a BOM it is more related with the implementation of the code you use in a app server (like using classloaders in your application which should always be avoided etc.)....or things like singletons in classical manner...better use CDI etc. for such things...

Comment: When you mention "using classloaders in your application" you mean declarations like that inside the code that should be avoided to prevent Classloader leaks? Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() or 
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream or 
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource ?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource... shouldn't be a problem..but what i'm asking myself about this is. Why do you need getContextClassLoader()... ? If it is a resource shouldn't getClass().getResources...() work as well? Reading of the classloader shouldn't be a problem but changing it with an app server...?

Comment: I am not changing, just reading :)

Comment: Ok..Than this is not problem..Some people  to do some kind of thread handling them selfs (cause they believe they could do it better) within a app server which leads to issues with thread pools as well a permGemSpace problems...Ok...